# How to enforce AAD Application Role authorization with Azure Functions?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, authorization, azure-functions

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps) describes how to add *Application* app roles to an application in Azure Active Directory using the manifest.

**Code sample from the page:**

```
"appId": "8763f1c4-f988-489c-a51e-158e9ef97d6a",
"appRoles": [
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "Application"
      ],
      "displayName": "ConsumerApps",
      "id": "47fbb575-859a-4941-89c9-0f7a6c30beac",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "Consumer apps have access to the consumer data.",
      "value": "Consumer"
    }
  ],
"availableToOtherTenants": false,
```

When calling an an Azure Function from an application authenticated using the `client_credentials` grant type, how do you enforce it to belong to the application role?

I've Googled but been unable to find clear documentation that explains how this authorization is done for Azure Functions.

---

**My Test Function App**

I've created a simple "hello <name>" Azure Function from within the Azure Portal which I call from Postman.

```
#r "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http"
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;


public static IActionResult Run(HttpRequest req,  ILogger log, ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal)
{
    var name = req.Query["name"];
    log.LogInformation($"C# HTTP trigger function processed a request: {name}");

    var cp = new {
        Identity = new {
            claimsPrincipal.Identity.AuthenticationType,
            claimsPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated,
            claimsPrincipal.Identity.Name
        },
        Claims = claimsPrincipal.Claims.Select(claim => new
        {
            claim.Type,
            claim.Value
        })
    };
    log.LogInformation($"ClaimsPrincipal ({claimsPrincipal.GetType().FullName}): {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cp, Formatting.Indented)}");

    return (IActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}");
}
```

Firstly I authenticate using `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<Tenant ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token` and capture the `access_token`.

**Request Body Example:**

```
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:<Application ID>
client_secret:<Client Secret>
scope:https://<Function-app-name>.azurewebsites.net/.default
```

**Example Result:**

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "ext_expires_in": 3599,
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAi......"
}
```

Then I call my Azure Function using `https://<function-app-name>.azurewebsites.net/api/hello?name=World` and a header containing `Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAi......`.

Authentication works fine, as does calling the Azure Function. However, I can add a new Application via **App registrations** in the Azure Portal, authenticate and then call the Azure Function freely. I don't know how to restrict access the the Azure Function to only Applications that have a specific application role.

Comment: Please show how did you call the function.

Comment: @JoyWang I've added it into the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I don't know how to restrict access the Azure Function to only Applications that have a specific application role.

If you just want the App who has the `ConsumerApps` permission access your function, follow the steps below.

1.Navigate to the AD App of your function in the Azure Active Directory in the portal -> click the `Managed application in local directory` -> `Properties` -> set the `User assignment required` to `Yes`.

[image]

[image]

2.Then you could try to get the token with your AD App again, you will find the app could not get the token successfully, you will get the error like below, because your client app does not have the `ConsumerApps` permission.

[image]

3.To access the function successfully, we just need to add the Application permission for the Client AD App you used.

Navigate to the client AD App in the portal -> `API permissions` -> `Add a permission` -> click `APIs my organization uses` -> search for your function AD App name -> click the app -> `Application permissions` -> add the `Consumer` permission -> **click the `Grant admin consent for xxx` button**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Wait for a while, then try to get the token again, it works fine.

[image]

Use the token to call function, also works.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried that and it worked. **"User assignment required?"** was what I was missing.I noticed that the app role appears as a _"roles"_ claim which I can interrogate. Unfortunately `ClaimsPrincipal.IsInRole()` doesn't work though, because the ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType property is set to `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role` instead of `roles`. But I can work around that.

Comment: @JoyWang, thank you for the detailed explanation. This setup works great for the clients in our organization. How can we add similar security if the client is outside the organization? Say, we have a microservice (azure function) and some third party app wants to access this microservice? Any help would be appreciated.