# The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[Microsoft.ContainerApps.ApiResources.Models.UnauthenticatedClientAction

Tags: azure-cli, azure-container-apps

I have an Azure Container App and I want to enable Authentication with Azure CLI:
[az containerapp auth update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp/auth?view=azure-cli-latest#az-containerapp-auth-update)

```bash
resourceGroup='lorem'
appName='ipsum'
az containerapp auth update --resource-group $resourceGroup --name $appName --enabled true --unauthenticated-client-action RejectWith401
```

This results in the following error:

> Bad Request({"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-13a7f69e4ce3b84f82e3b7d2c0425143-5ec6db570ab2989b-01","errors":{"$.properties.globalValidation.unauthenticatedClientAction":["The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[Microsoft.ContainerApps.ApiResources.Models.UnauthenticatedClientAction]. Path: $.properties.globalValidation.unauthenticatedClientAction | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 114."]}})

The [Optional Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp/auth?view=azure-cli-latest#az-containerapp-auth-update-optional-parameters) support this:

> --action --unauthenticated-client-action
> The action to take when an unauthenticated client attempts to access the app.
> accepted values:
> AllowAnonymous, RedirectToLoginPage, RejectWith401, RejectWith404

The same error is returned when I use

```bash
--action RejectWith401
```

It's working in Azure Portal, but I need this in the CI/CD pipeline.

[image: Azure Portal - Authentication settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar problem at StackOverflow:
[Unable to set unauthenticatedClientAction with Az module or Az/CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61483051/unable-to-set-unauthenticatedclientaction-with-az-module-or-az-cli)

> --set properties.siteAuthSettings.unauthenticatedClientAction=AllowAnonymous

The *--set* parameter is also present for *az containerapp*:
[ContainerApp --set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp/auth?view=azure-cli-latest#az-containerapp-auth-update-optional-parameters)

> --set
> Value of a specific field within the configuration settings for the Azure App Service Authentication / Authorization feature.

After enabling Authentication in Azure Portal, Azure CLI returned for *show*:

```bash
resourceGroup='lorem'
appName='ipsum'
az containerapp auth show --resource-group $resourceGroup --name $appName
```

```json
{
  "globalValidation": {
    "unauthenticatedClientAction": "Return401"
  },...
}
```

Based on the gathered information I was successful enabling Authentication with:

```bash
resourceGroup='lorem'
appName='ipsum'
az containerapp auth update --resource-group $resourceGroup --name $appName --enabled true --set globalValidation.unauthenticatedClientAction=Return401
```

```json
{
  "name": "current",
  "properties": {
    "globalValidation": {
      "unauthenticatedClientAction": "Return401"
    },...
    "platform": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "resourceGroup": "lorem",
  "type": "Microsoft.App/containerapps/authconfigs"
}
```

Comment: This saved the day! thanks.