# How to restrict access to an azure function based on a service principal id

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

I have a REST API implemented as an Azure function with Azure Active Directory authentication enabled. I would like to restrict the access to a subset of of the exposed methods to a particular set of service principals.

So far the solution I have come up with is to retrieve access_token used by the request and check the application Id against a list manually. This will be done in the body of the the method.

I am looking for a solution that could handle this in the Azure authorization layer before even calling the function. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in another reply, there is no such thing currently. If you want to restrict the access of the function app for a set of service principals, my workaround is to declare an [`app role`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#declare-app-roles-using-azure-portal) for the AD App related to your function app, as the sample below.

```
"appId": "8763f1c4-f988-489c-a51e-158e9ef97d6a",
"appRoles": [
    {
      "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "Application"
      ],
      "displayName": "ConsumerApps",
      "id": "47fbb575-859a-4941-89c9-0f7a6c30beac",
      "isEnabled": true,
      "description": "Consumer apps have access to the consumer data.",
      "value": "Consumer"
    }
  ],
"availableToOtherTenants": false,
```

After that, navigate to the AD App of your function in the Azure Active Directory in the portal -> click the `Managed application in local directory` -> `Properties` -> `set the User assignment required` to `Yes`.

Then any service principal used to get the token for the function app needs the application permission you declared, otherwise it will not be able to get the token. I wrote the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61224922/9455659), you could refer to it.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing ready to use for that. One thing you can do is use custom handlers and implement the logic outside your function logic:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-custom-handlers